# Setting up a secure connection between a node.js server and a jQuery client

Tags: jquery, node.js, ssl, encryption

Here is an example. The following is skeleton code for a node.js https server.

```
var https = require("https");
var port = //port number here    
https.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //request handling code
}).listen(port);
```

Assuming that the website the server runs on has an SSL certificate, can I simply make requests with the jQuery get and getJSON functions, passing it a https url? Would this be sufficient to encrypt the requests such that no third party can intercept the request nor the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know/use node.js but I do know jquery and javascript. Short answer to your question is Yes.

So long as the server is configured for HTTPS, calls from your javascript code will be encrypted by the browser going over the wire. Same with the response headers/data.